# How do I select edges properties where the vertices share a common property?

Tags: groovy, neo4j, gremlin

I had like to filter vertex names ( overlap ) by comparing one property of each edge's .

Suppose I have a simple dataset as :

```
A  --> 100  --> B
A  --> 200  --> C
A  --> 100  --> D
```

See in the above I want to show common vertices based on edge property (100, 200 etc) like :

```
A 100 B
A 100 D
```

This is the Gremlin code I tried :

```
g.V.outE('give').filter{it.amt.next() == it.amt.next()}
```

also not able to output using has clause ? It doesn't return any results. What have I missed ?

Comment: can it be by  groupCount(amt) and then if it is > 1 then those the repeting vertex with common edge property i.e amt .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use groupBy operation (a similar recommendation was made by @abhi in the comments to use groupCount):

```
gremlin> g = new TinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> a = g.addVertex("A") 
==>v[A]
gremlin> b = g.addVertex("B") 
==>v[B]
gremlin> c = g.addVertex("C")              
==>v[C]
gremlin> d = g.addVertex("D")                
==>v[D]
gremlin> g.addEdge(a, b, 'give', [amt:100])
==>e[0][A-give->B]
gremlin> g.addEdge(a, c, 'give', [amt:200])
==>e[1][A-give->C]
gremlin> g.addEdge(a, d, 'give', [amt:100])
==>e[2][A-give->D]
gremlin> g.V.outE('give').groupBy{it.amt}{[it.outV.next(), it.inV.next()]}.cap.next()
==>100=[[v[A], v[D]], [v[A], v[B]]]
==>200=[[v[A], v[C]]]
```

To limit the results to just those that have more than one match you can just post process the map with groovy (in this case with findAll):

```
gremlin> m=[:];g.V.outE('give').groupBy(m){it.amt}{[it.outV.next(), it.inV.next()]}        
==>e[2][A-give->D]
==>e[1][A-give->C]
==>e[0][A-give->B]
gremlin> m
==>100=[[v[A], v[D]], [v[A], v[B]]]
==>200=[[v[A], v[C]]]
gremlin> m.findAll{it.value.size()>1}
==>100=[[v[A], v[D]], [v[A], v[B]]]
```

Comment: can i restrict the output which will displays only the rows which has more then two nodes. i mean in the above only the row 1 from the result. like {it.inV.next().count().size() > 1..

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to ask specific questions with real world examples than generalizing the problems. Based upon my understanding, below is the Cypher notation. I am giving an example in Cypher that I think you can convert to Gremlin. If you doesn't want it then comment and I will delete this response.

**Setup**

```
CREATE (A { name: 'A' })-[:GAVE { amount: 100 }]->(B { name: 'B' }) 
CREATE A-[:GAVE { amount: 200 }]->(C { name: 'C' }) 
CREATE A-[:GAVE { amount: 100 }]->(D { name: 'D' })
```

**Query**

Returns all the Nodes (vertices) where the amount is 100.

```
MATCH n1-[gave:GAVE]->n2 
WHERE gave.amount=100 
RETURN n1.name, gave.amount, n2.name
```

You can try this in the [console here](http://console.neo4j.org/r/sf6gak).

Update your question with real world example and better setup the test data in neo4j.console.org and then Share it by clicking the **Share** button on top of the console.

Comment: thanks :) due to sensitive data ..I sent a rough example. Will follow your suggestion.